# method cannot be applied to given types when trying to perform a generic binary search

Tags: java, generics, types, comparable

Let's say I have a class called `RandomObject`:

```
public class RandomObject implements Comparable<RandomObject> {

    private String name;
    private int value;

    public RandomObject(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

          . 
          .
          .

    public int compareTo(RandomObject rn) {
        return Integer.compare(value, rn.value);
    }
```

And this array of `RandomObject`s (each one of them holding a random int value that will be used for comparison purposes):

```
RandomObject[] arr = new RandomObject[10];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = new RandomObject(" ", (int) (Math.random() * 50));
    }
```

I also have a class called `Quicksort` containing the following sort methods:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] a) {
    sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] a, int start, int end) {
    int left = start, right = end;
    T pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];

    do {
        while (a[left].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
            left++;
        }
        while (a[right].compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
            right--;
        }
        if (left <= right) {
            T temp = a[left];
            a[left++] = a[right];
            a[right--] = temp;
        }
    } while (left <= right);

    if (start < right) {
        sort(a, start, right);
    }
    if (left < end) {
        sort(a, left, end);
    }
}
```

Calling `Quicksort.sort(arr)` works normally and sorts `arr` by value.

However, I also have a `BinarySearch` class with the following `search` method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int search(T[] a, T value) {
    int start = 0, end = a.length - 1;
    do {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (a[mid].compareTo(value) == 0) {
            return mid;
        } else if (a[mid].compareTo(value) > 0) {
            end = mid;
        } else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    } while (start < end);
    return -1;
}
```

And when I try to perform a search like this:

```
Integer x = 2;
System.out.println("Trying to find x: " + BinarySearch.search(arr, x));
```

Something goes wrong:

> "java: method search in class br.com.algorithms.BinarySearch cannot be applied to given types;
> required: T[],T
> found:    br.com.algorithms.RandomObject[],java.lang.Integer
> reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
> lower bounds: br.com.algorithms.RandomObject,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Comparable<? super T>
> lower bounds: java.lang.Integer,br.com.algorithms.RandomObject"

[no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that RandomObject conforms to an Integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlfUr.png)

I'm struggling to understand why the `sort` method works while the `search` one doesn't in this case. If both methods require `T[]` and I am providing `RandomObject[]` for both cases, why isn't search compiling? What's exactly the difference here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's exactly the difference here?

`search` takes a `T[]` and a `T`, which means that the array element type of the first parameter needs to be the same as the type of the second parameter. You have given it `RandomObject[]` and `Integer`, which is clearly not valid.

On the other hand, `sort` only takes a single `T[]`, so you can just give it any reference type array, and there is no further constraints *between* parameters. After all, there is only *one* parameter.

Note that it is impossible to search for an integer in a `RandomObject[]` with your current implementation. This is because `compareTo` compares instances of `RandomObject`. It does not compare `RandomObject`s against `Integer`s.

What you can do instead, is create a "dummy" `RandomObject` using `x`, and pass that to `search`:

```
int x = 1;
RandomObject key = new RandomObject("this does not matter", x);
System.out.println("Trying to find x: " + BinarySearch.search(arr, key));
```

You can also create a non-generic version of `search` that only searches `RandomObject[]`. In this non-generic version, you can change the second parameter to `int`:

```
public static int search(RandomObject[] a, int value) { ... }
```

But in a generic method, it is difficult to know what key the caller wants to search by. It is not impossible though - you can create such an interface:

```
interface BinarySearchableByKey<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    T getKey();
}
```

Instead of (or in addition to) implementing `Comparable`, `RandomObject` should implement `BinarySearchableByKey<Integer>`, as it is searchable by an integer key.

```
public class RandomObject implements BinarySearchableByKey<Integer> {
    // ...

    @Override
    public Integer getKey() { return value; }
}
```

Change `search` to have two type parameters - the array's type, and the search key type:

```
public static <K extends Comparable<? super K>, T extends BinarySearchableByKey<? extends K>> int search(T[] a, K value) {
    int start = 0, end = a.length - 1;
    do {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (a[mid].getKey().compareTo(value) == 0) {
            return mid;
        } else if (a[mid].getKey().compareTo(value) > 0) {
            end = mid;
        } else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    } while (start < end);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If both methods require T[] and I am providing RandomObject[] for both cases

The binary search argument requires two things: a `T[]` and a `T`.

You are providing a `RandomObject[]` and an `Integer`.  Those aren't the same T.  Your binary search method would expect a `RandomObject[]` and a `RandomObject`.